# Apache Spark: How 200 Reducer Tasks Can Aggregate 20000+ Mapper Output?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

**Updated Question**

What I am not Clear about =>
in **ShuffleMapStage** each Mapper will create a **.data** and a **.index** file

These **data/index** will have a **name** like

`shuflle_X_Y_Z`

where

**X** = `shuffle_id`

**Y** = `map_id`

**Z** = `REDUCER_ID`

**I Understand map_id can range from 1-222394**

**BUT HOW ABOUT REDUCER_ID** ?

**is it 1-200 (e.g default partition for ResultStage) ?**

**is it = # of Executors ?**

**if it is 1-200 then does how these 200 tasks Know which data/index file to read ?**

Help me to understand that

I am at a loss in understanding how **Reduce/Aggergation** tasks work ?
Say I have a Simple Example Like

```
input_df = spark.read.parquet("Big_folder_having parquets")

# Spark loads and during reading partitions = as per number of files * number of 128MB blocks.

# Now I do a Simple Aggergation/Count 

input_df.createOrReplaceTempView("table1")

grouped_df = spark.sql("select key1, key2, count(1) as user_count from table1 group by 1,2")

# And simply write it with default 200 parallelism

grouped_df.write.format("parquet").mode("overwrite").save(my_save_path)
```

So for **input load** the **parent rdd/input map Stage** has **22394** partitions

As I understand each mapper will create a **shuflle data and index file**

Now **next stage** has only **200** tasks (**default shuffle partitions**)

**How can these 200 reducers/tasks process output from 22394 mapper tasks** ?

Attached **DAG Screenshot**
[image]

Comment: did you try changing value of   ``` spark.sql.shuffle.partitions ```  to more than 200 and see? You can increase this value and set as per your requirement

Comment: @naga . That's not the question.

Answer I am looking for how (200 or Smaller) numbers of Reducers can **aggregate** 20000+ mapper output ?

Comment: @SanBan 200 is the default number of partitions after grouping, see `spark.sql.shuffle.partitions` property. If you are asking how does it possible join 20,000 input partitions into only 200 output partitions, than I believe Spark save intermediate results on disk before shuffle, and send them over the network. Each receiver/executor than have process ~100 input partitions, I think it doesn't keep everything in memory, and spill partial (or even final) results to disk. You can check spill property at Saprk UI, stage or task details, don't remember

Answer (score 2):

You have a cluster with 40 cores.

What happens is:

You ask Spark to read the files in the directory, it will do it 40 tasks at a time (since that is the number of cores you got) and the result will be a RDD that will have 22,394 partitions. (Be careful about shuffle spill. Check the stage details.)

Then you ask Spark to group your data by some keys and then write it out.

Since the default shuffle partitions is 200, Spark will "move" the data from 22,394 partitions into 200 partitions and process 40 tasks/partitions at a time.

In other words...

When you request to group and save Spark will create plans (I recommend you investigate physical and logical plans) and it will say... "In order to do what the user is asking me to, I will create 200 tasks that will be executed against the data"

Then the executors will execute 40 tasks at a time.

There aren't mappers or reducers per se.

There are tasks that Spark will create and there are executors which will execute those tasks.

Edit:

Forgot to mention, the number of the partitions in the RDD will determine the number of output files.

Comment: ==> My question is :
from 22394 Partition I shall have 22394 shuffle *Index/data* file which shows key(join key), value ) pair.
**How can 200 tasks in next Stage Handle 100 TIMES more mapper input ?

Answer (score 0):

If you have 10 buckets with 10 apples or 1 bucket with 100 apples, it's all the same total apples.

Asking how it can handle it is similar to asking how can you carry 10 buckets or carry 1 bucket.

It will either do it or it won't depending on the amount of data you have. Issue you can have is data being spilled to disk because when having 200 partitions each partition needs to handle more data which may not necessarily fit into memory.